# How to stop Duplicate value in this code

Tags: javascript

How to stop Duplicate value in this code

**HTML**

```
   <ul class="care-ul">
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Disease" /> Disease</a></li>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Failure"/> Failure</a></li>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Wounds"/>  Wounds</a></li>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Afib"/> Afib</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var carevalue = [];

function questionCount() {

    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        carevalue.push(value);
    });           

    var json = JSON.stringify(carevalue);
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    $('.new-lists li').html(obj);
        }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#apply').click(function () {
        questionCount();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$('.new-lists li').html(obj);` is this statement adding new link `li` item to `ul`? or you just trying to show selected values in blank link item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to test if value already added to the array:
Here is a working Snippet

```js
var carvalue = [];

function questionCount() {

    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(carvalue.indexOf(value)==-1)
        carvalue.push(value);
       
    });           

    var json = JSON.stringify(carvalue);
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(obj);
    $('.new-lists li').html(obj);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#apply').click(function () {
        questionCount();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="care-ul">
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Disease" /> Disease</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Failure"/> Failure</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Wounds"/>  Wounds</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Afib"/> Afib</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="new-lists">
   <li>
</ul>
<button id="apply">Apply</button>
```

if you want to **remove unchecked** values 
use this code snippet

```js
var carvalue = [];
function questionCount() {
  $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]'), function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(this.checked){
      if(carvalue.indexOf(value)==-1) 
          carvalue.push(value);
    }else{
      if(carvalue.indexOf(value)>-1)
          carvalue.splice(carvalue.indexOf(value), 1);
    }
  });
  var json = JSON.stringify(carvalue);
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  $('.new-lists li').html(obj);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#apply').click(function () {
    questionCount();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="care-ul">
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Disease" /> Disease</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Failure"/> Failure</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Wounds"/>  Wounds</a></li>
    <li><a><input type="checkbox" value="Afib"/> Afib</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="new-lists">
   <li>
</ul>
<button id="apply">Apply</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to intialize `carevalue` array in the `questionCount` method everytime rather than only intializing it outside.

```
function questionCount() {

    carevalue = []; //now it will lose initial values so only new unique values will be coming
    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        carevalue.push(value);
    });           

    var json = JSON.stringify(carevalue);
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    $('.new-lists li').html(obj);
}
```